# Test if an S3 object was created or updated when using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-3.8

Is it possible to determine whether or not an S3 object was created or updated when using `boto3`?

When using [`boto3.client('s3').put_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) to create or update S3 objects, the underlying PutObject API action doesn't differentiate between creating and updating objects, so `ResponseMetadata.HTTPStatusCode` is always 200.

There is no `post_object()` method for `boto3.client('s3')`, nor is there a `post` method for [`boto3.resource('s3').object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object). In fact, it doesn't appear that there is a `PostObject` API action anyway.

```py
import boto3
import base
import base64

client = boto3.client('s3')
body = 'Hello World!'

response = client.put_object(
    Bucket='my-bucket',
    Key='my-key.json',
    Body=body.encode('utf-8'))

print('S3 object successfully created. Or was it updated????')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "updating" an object. In S3 you always fully replace them, which means you have to upload entire "updated" object.

But if your bucket is **versioned**, you can always track the "update" status of your objects yourself, by checking their `Date` [metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html#SysMetadata) attribute.

There is also [Last-Modified](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html#SysMetadata) attribute which you can inspect and compare with `Date` attribute to check if they are different.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't specifically need versioned objects, it's just the user needs to be informed whether or not an object was created or replaced (they'll be told updated). I assume that the only way to retrieve the metadata including last-modified is through a `head_object()` request? If that's the case, I won't need to worry out checking the metadata and I can just test of object existence prior to the `put_object()` operation.

Comment: @DavidGard yes, just checking with `head_object()` before `put_object()` is probably the easiest solution in your scenario.